# PageRank job on Apache giraph is not producing output file

Tags: giraph

**Command:**

```
hduser@bigtapp:/usr/local/giraph$ hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimplePageRankComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/input/tiny.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/output/SimplePageRank -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```

**Result:**

> 15/05/07 11:28:38 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge input format
>   specified. Ensure your InputFormat does not require one. 15/05/07
>   11:28:38 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge output format
>   specified. Ensure your OutputFormat does not require one. 15/05/07
>   11:28:38 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: Setting custom argument
>   [giraph.SplitMasterWorker] to [false] in GiraphConfiguration 15/05/07
>   11:28:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop
>   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where
>   applicable 15/05/07 11:28:39 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   mapreduce.job.counters.limit is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.job.counters.max 15/05/07 11:28:39 INFO
>   Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.map.memory.mb is deprecated.
>   Instead, use mapreduce.map.memory.mb 15/05/07 11:28:39 INFO
>   Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb is deprecated.
>   Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 15/05/07 11:28:39 INFO
>   Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative 15/05/07 11:28:39
>   INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.user.classpath.first is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first 15/05/07
>   11:28:39 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.max.attempts is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.maxattempts 15/05/07 11:28:39
>   INFO job.GiraphJob: run: Since checkpointing is disabled (default), do
>   not allow any task retries (setting mapred.map.max.attempts = 1, old
>   value = 4) 15/05/07 11:28:39 INFO Configuration.deprecation:
>   mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.jobtracker.address 15/05/07 11:28:39 INFO client.RMProxy:
>   Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 15/05/07 11:28:42 INFO
>   mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1 15/05/07 11:28:42 INFO
>   mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job:
>   job_1430974889906_0002 15/05/07 11:28:42 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl:
>   Submitted application application_1430974889906_0002 15/05/07 11:28:42
>   INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job:
>   http://bigtapp:8088/proxy/application_1430974889906_0002/ 15/05/07
>   11:28:42 INFO job.GiraphJob: Tracking URL:
>   http://bigtapp:8088/proxy/application_1430974889906_0002/ 15/05/07
>   11:28:42 INFO job.GiraphJob: Waiting for resources... Job will start
>   only when it gets all 2 mappers 15/05/07 11:28:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:
>   Running job: job_1430974889906_0002 15/05/07 11:28:55 INFO
>   mapreduce.Job: Job job_1430974889906_0002 running in uber mode : false
>   15/05/07 11:28:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0% 15/05/07
>   11:28:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1430974889906_0002 failed with
>   state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1430974889906_0002_m_000000 Job
>   failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
>
> 15/05/07 11:28:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8     Job Counters 
>         Failed map tasks=1      Launched map tasks=1        Other local map tasks=1
>         Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=5785        Total
>   time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0        Total time spent
>   by all map tasks (ms)=5785        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map
>   tasks=5785        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=5923840

Comment: I am running the giraph job it is not generating the output file.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for formatting the question in a proper manner.Exactly the problem is  :mapreduce.Job: Job job_1430974889906_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1430974889906_0002_m_000000 Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0.                                                                                        So job is forcefully killed and not generating output file.can anyone help me on this???